# Weird application of "FIND" function

Tags: excel-formula

I encountered one weird application of the "FIND" function which I don't quite know how it work. Could someone enlighten me?

This formula results in "19"
=MEDIAN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},"2 notch lower0123456789"))

This formula results in "23"
=MAX(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},"2 notch lower0123456789"))

This formula results in "1"
=MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},"2 notch lower0123456789"))

This formula results in "15"
=FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},"2 notch lower0123456789")

The results obviously tie with the number of characters. But how exactly does this syxtax of FIND work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

First, because of the matrix argument, `FIND()` runs in a loop, for the values 1, 2, ...9 (as specified inside the {}).

`FIND` returns then the position of the first match inside the string `"2 notch lower0123456789"`, for each number (as a character), so the 1 is found at position 15, the 2 at position 1, the 3 at position 17, the 4 at position 18, etc, until the 9 is found at position 23.

The result of this matrix operation will be the list {15,1,17,18,19,20,21,22,23}.

Now apply the functions to that:

`MEDIAN({15,1,17,18,19,20,21,22,23})` -> the middle value is 19!

`MAX({15,1,17,18,19,20,21,22,23})` -> obviously 23

`MIN({15,1,17,18,19,20,21,22,23})` -> obviously 1

`{15,1,17,18,19,20,21,22,23}` -> if you don't apply anything to it, a matrix gets reduced to the first element, so 15.

Definitely *weird usage*, I agree.

Comment: Thanks, Aganju ! Got it now.